# react-native-math-view can't find variable require

Tags: react-native

While importing MathText and Mathview, im getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBjUD.png). There is no error in install. How can I fix this?

I have tried to reset cache, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, I had the same issue, but I downgraded to "react-native-math-view": "3.9.4", which solved the issue. Remember to delete node_modules and npm install again and reset your cache